# Использование Doctrine в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, doctrine

Для работы использую `Laravel`. Как многие знают, в качестве `ORM` там используется библиотека `Eloquent`. Дело в том, что я читал много различных статей, где люди настаивали на том, что использовать `Doctrine` вместо `Eloquent` будет очень хорошей идеей. Вот я и решил перейти на `Doctrine`. Но есть одна проблема. Как поставить `Doctrine` вместо `Eloquent` в `Laravel`? Я нашёл библиотеку, которая специально была написана под Laravel http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/, но не знаю, стоит ли использовать её, или взять с официального сайта `Doctrine`. Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно поступить? И с какими проблемами я могу встретиться при использовании `Doctrine` вместо `Eloquent` в `Laravel`?

Comment: Неразумно переходить на что-то по совету людей, если они не могут объяснить преимущества перехода  или вы не можете понять их объяснений.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин А с чего вы взяли, что я решил перейти на Doctrine просто так? Естественно, что я ознакомился с минусами и плюсами разных ORM и понял, что Doctrine для моих целей подходит больше.

Comment: мне так показалось. На мой взгляд захотеть перейти с Eloquent на  Doctrine можно либо при недостаточной опытности или наоборот при опытности чрезмерной :-) При чрезмерной опытности у вас бы не возникло вопросов по интеграции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как поставить Doctrine вместо Eloquent в Laravel?

Через composer `composer require doctrine/orm`. Вот официальный [гайд](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html).

Проект Laravel Doctrine - это обвязка для использования Доктрины внутри Laravel. На [сайте проекта](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.4/orm) прямым текстом сказано, что делает этот пакет:

- простая конфигурация
- пагинация
- предустановленные метаданные, коннекты и кеширование
- стратегия наименования как в Laravel
- имплементация авторизации и восстановления паролей
- ... и много других фичей

Ставится это также через композер `composer require "laravel-doctrine/orm:1.3.*"` плюс нужна настройка, вот [официальный гайд](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/docs/1.4/orm/installation).

Таким образом, у вас есть выбор - либо ставить Доктрину самостоятельно, и затем интегрировать - делать все то, что заявлено как фичи Laravel Doctrine, либо использовать этот готовый пакет. Решать вам.

> И с какими проблемами я могу встретиться при использовании Doctrine вместо Eloquent в Laravel

Вообще, полезно смотреть исходные коды. А также - тесты.

В [тестах этого пакета](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm/tree/1.7/tests) есть валидация, а это значит, что валидация от Лары с голой Доктриной работать не будет. Нужно дорабатывать.

Далее по списку - пагинация, конфигурация, сериализация, кеширование, ..., кажется, я писал это выше. Просто сейчас смотрю тесты, и в них этот заявленный функционал проверяется. И требует реализации, если хотите использовать голую Доктрину, но оставить подход `Eloquent`.

> Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно поступить?

Хотите разобраться, как подружить Доктрину и Лару? Тогда установите ее начните использовать, сталкиваться с трудностями и решать их. Можно подсматривать в исходные коды того проекта.

Нужен простой путь - просто поставьте пакет. Но там тоже не все так гладко, смотрите [Issues на Гитхабе](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm/issues)